# Finding unmatched records in MYSQL in a m2m scenario

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in a m2m relationship in a mysql database as follows:

```
tbltest (test_id, testdescription)
tblprofile (profile_id, profiledescription)
tbltestprofile(testprofile_id,test_id,profile_id)
```

I need to display test_id and description from the test table where I have no matching records in tbltestprofile and where the profile_id = x

I've tried various combinations using NOT IN but without the desired results. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Your requirements confuse me.  How can both conditions "no matching records in testprofile" and "profile_id = x" be true? Those seem like contradictions to me. I think you need to provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT test_id
     , testdescription
FROM tbltest AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM tbltestprofile tp 
        WHERE t.test_id = tp.test_id
          AND tp.profile_id = X
      )
```

---

---

Sidenote. It would help if you kept table (and field) names simple and not add the `tbl` prefix, like `test`, `profile`, `testprofile`. A simple 3-table join you have probably used:

```
SELECT tbltest.test_id
     , tbltest.testdescription
     , tblprofile.profile_id
     , tblprofile.profiledescription
FROM tbltest
  JOIN tbltestprofile
    ON tbltest.test_id = tbltestprofile.test_id
  JOIN tblprofile
    ON tblprofile.profile_id = tbltestprofile.profile_id
ORDER BY tblprofile.profiledescription
```

makes me rather dizzy. Wouldn't it be better like this? Even without aliases:

```
SELECT test.id              AS test_id
     , test.description     AS test
     , profile.id           AS profile_id
     , profile.description  AS profile
FROM test
  JOIN testprofile
    ON test.id = testprofile.test_id
  JOIN profile
    ON profile.id = testprofile.profile_id
ORDER BY profile.description
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My Actual tables don't have the tbl prefix. I prefixed them in my example above to make it clear that they were my 3 tables. Completely Unecesssary. Something that's not clear to me - what is the significance of the tp at the end of the line FROM tbltestprofile tp ?

Comment: It's an alias. `FROM tbltestprofile tp` is the same as `FROM tbltestprofile AS tp`. It's not required and I sometimes forget to put the `AS`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT test_id, testdescription
FROM tbltest
LEFT JOIN tbltestprofile ON tbltest.test_id = tbltestprofile.test_id
WHERE tbltestprofile.test_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: If you added the `AND tbltestprofile.profile_id = X` in the `ON` condition, it would be equivalent to my answer.

Comment: Ah... your answer makes his question make sense to me.